# SQL SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I cannot understand why SQL is giving me two very different numbers for a simple GROUP BY for calculating values in a table. I'm using a SUM of 2 columns.

I'll try and break it down to the simplest key components of the system.

```
Ledger:  
| increase | decrease | userid | currency

Users:  
| email | role |
```

`userid` is FK to `id` on users table, there are no orphan rows.

**And now for the query:**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(l.increase) - SUM(l.decrease) as total
FROM ledger l 
JOIN users u ON l.userid = u.id AND u.role = 'customer'
WHERE l.currency = 'USD'
GROUP BY u.email
ORDER BY total DESC
```

The above yields a 145 rows of users. I can put it in a sub query to get what I believe is the true SUM

```
SELECT SUM(tmp.total) FROM (<ABOVE_AS_SUBQUERY>) as tmp
```

and **I get 8042**.

**Here's my second query:**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(l.increase) - SUM(l.decrease) as total
FROM ledger l 
JOIN users u ON l.userid = u.id AND u.role = 'customer'
WHERE l.currency = 'USD'
GROUP BY u.role
ORDER BY total DESC
```

This time I've grouped by role, in-fact, I can remove the GROUP BY all-together and it behaves the same.  **I get 99104**.

Surely the results should be the same. Especially as my join condition is already filtering `role='customer'`.

`GROUP BY u.email` gives me a set of totals unique to each email, but I don't understand why removing the GROUP by gives me a number so far beyond what's in the data-set after a GROUP BY that something weird is clearly happening. Why is the resulting row not just the SUM of all those emails and giving me 8042?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9ed15/2). The 2 queries return the same result, as I would have originally expected. I cannot replicate this problem in this fiddle meaning it is related to the data, but there's only 2 tables at play here. What sort of data can I use to replicate what I am describing?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  If you could replicate this on a small sample of data, a db fiddle would also be a big help.

Comment: @phi Why does the group matter in this scenario? my JOIN is also `ON u.role = 'customer'`. I am literally only selecting rows with a role of customer, so SUM with or without group would be the same. SUM on GROUP of emails would ALSO be the same because it is still getting a SUM of each unique email, which would total up to the same amount overall.

Comment: Added a fiddle :)

Comment: I didn't say that the group mattered. I was just responding to "I don't understand why removing the GROUP by gives me" for you to confirm whatever parts of your expectations re GROUP BY per se were relevant. PS Please put everything needed for your question in it, including the code, not just in a link. Please don't append/insert EDIT sections, edit to rewrite to the best presentation possible. PS To find smaller representative problem input, keep halving the problem data until you binary search to an appropriate subset. Also: NULLs are suspected culprits so select/count/sort for them.

Comment: You show nulls in your data, do you understand the answer that addresses getting different sums per SUM & + because of them treating nulls differently? Did you look at every subexpression result with your problem data to see when you don't get what you expect? Select the SUMs separately, not just their difference? (More basic debugging.)

Answer (score 1):

I would believe the answer without the `GROUP BY`.

What may be happening is that `NULL` values are "interfering" with the result.  `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values, so if all non-`NULL` values will be added together.  However, `+` does not ignore `NULL` values.  If *either* operand is `NULL`, then the result is `NULL`.

If, for instance, you have a name where all the `decrease` values are `NULL`.  For instance:

```
email    role     increase    decrease
  a       1          10         5
  b       1          20         NULL
```

In this simple example, aggregating by email would result in:

```
 a      5      -- 10 - 5 = 5
 b      NULL   -- 20 - NULL = NULL
```

But by role it would be:

```
 1      25     -- sum(10 + 20) - sum(5 + NULL) = 30 - 5 = 25
```

You don't mention `NULL` values in the question, but they may be the culprit.

Comment: Nice idea, I do have NULLS exactly as you say. I think `SUM(column)` though doesn't care for NULLS. `SUM(decrease)` in your example would be (5 + null) which SQL interprets as `5`. It doesn't SUM the (increase - decrease) per row. I see by role though, it may well behave like that.. interesting, but then I'd expect to see lower numbers, not higher!

Comment: I think this MIGHT be to do with NULLS the more I look at it. I can pull the values in to MS excel and do it the simplest possible way where I am certain of the results, and I get the 99k value.